# help for user login

Tags: custom-field, login

please help,
I have to restrict some users based on the value of some metadata.for eg:if the account is not verified by admin(a metafield like "adminveri" will be zero), then the user should not login....please help me..

this is what i have done so far...
    add_filter('authenticate', 'check_login', 100, 3);

```
function check_login($user,$username,$password,$uid) 
{ 
 if(!empty($user)) $user_data=$user->data; 
 $adminveri=get_user_meta($uid,'admin_status');
$emailveri=get_user_meta($uid,'email_status'); 
if($adminveri[0]==0) or $emailveri[0]==0 ) 
{ 
return null;
} 
else 
{ 
return $user; 
} 
}
```

this code dont allow anyone to login...Also what is the difference between add_filter and add_action?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code. Spend a little more time forming a well-written question if you want someone to spend time helping you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the folowing to your themes's functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wpse_112895_validate_user', 10, 2 );

function wpse_112895_validate_user( $login, $user ) {
     $meta = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'adminveri', true );

     // not verified, log them out!
     if ( $meta != 0 )
         wp_logout();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response...but the wp_logout() is not working,ie anyone can login...if i use "return null;",any user including admin couldn't login...

Comment: How did you test to know it is not working?  Did you do a var_dump after the condition $meta != 0?  This is to know if that conditional even fires.  Also you didn't mention about admin logins before so this code obviously is generic.  You can further filter out the admin so this code doesn't affect them even if they don't have that meta value